# Can an aluminium chip with some engravings protect people from harmful effects of electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

I have come to know about a product called E-Guard by a company called QNET. They say that this small device (Just an aluminium piece with laser engravings) can protect us from harmful effects of electromagnetic radiations. How genuine is this concept of a small device protecting against radiation?

Product page: https://www.amezcua.com/E-Guard.html

Comment: What do you think, and why?  Further, what is your basis for thinkng "electromagnetic radiation" is harmful?  Are you aware that sunburn is one such mechanism?

Comment: This is snake oil. Save your money.

Comment: The point of the question is that the OP does not realize that this not a valid claim.  He is not proposing or supporting a crackpot theory,  he is trying to get information. This means he had doubts and needs help from professionals to resolve them. Other people may be in the same situation and benefit from the answers.

Comment: Exactly @nasu, Agents of these companies are fooling people, Trying to fetch some information to help some people.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you wanted to blockout electromagnetic ratiation from your body you would need to wear a Faraday cage (a metal mesh with holes smaller than the wavelength of the radiation you wish to block out) or alternative just a solid metal suit. A small piece of aluminium will not achieve this.

The fact you don't see scientists wearing such suits in everyday life should be an indication to whether they feel it is a necessary precaution. If you were going into a nuclear reactor or space it may be a different matter.